# MediaWiki template import reports "Error: no shortcuts were specified and the |msg= parameter was not set"

Tags: lua, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I exported the Template:Warning template from Wikipedia and tried it import it into my instance of MediaWiki.  The import was successful, but when I try to use the template, it just shows:

Template:Warning

on my page.

When I go to the Template:Warning page on my wiki, I see the following:

```
     {{#if: |
{{#if:| [[File:{{{image}}}|40px|Warning]] }}    {{#if: |'}}{{{1}}}  {{#if: |{{{imageright}}} |{{#if: |Error: no shortcuts were specified and the |msg= parameter was not set.}} }}
     }}{{{1}}}
```

Further down the page, I get:

```
{{#if:{{#ifeq:Warning|sandbox|1}}{{#ifeq:Warning|doc|1}}||{{#switch:Lua error: First parameter must be one of edit, move, create, upload, undelete, autoreview.|sysop|templateeditor|interfaceadmin=|#default=}}}}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most templates from Wikipedia depend on extensions not part of the MediaWiki core. In this case, it depends on [the ParserFunctions extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions). Install that on your wiki and then the template will work.

Comment: This worked.  Thank you!  I had to add some of the styles in MediaWiki/Common.css to make the warning look like that in Wikipedia.